# Coldfusion: create any prototype?

Tags: coldfusion

Hi while facing an interview one of the questions was 
"Did you create a Prototype"?
Now I had worked with 2 projects that involved the entire SDLC.

I said:

> Prototype Design – Created in the Preliminary Design Phase; expands the Conceptual Use Case Model to the Implementation Use Case Model.  It identifies the Actors and provides a Description of each use case in this subsystem or package.

I tried explaining them the above and they were not satisfied.

Can anyone tell me what is this Prototype vis-a-vis a Coldfusion project is?

Answer (score 4):

"Prototype" has no special meaning in the ColdFusion world. Since it seems they mean "Do you build working demos" and your answer was "yes" I don't understand why they would not have been satisfied unless they are playing semantic games.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, it is possible there was a communication error and your potential employer was  refering to the Prototype JavaScript Framework: http://www.prototypejs.org/?